# CodeIgniter News Site (Routing Index to different functions)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've recently started using codeigniter and i'm having a few issues with my routing. I feel like i may have missed something in the way that it's meant to work, despite reading the documentation.

I've currently managed to route the default controller to execute the correct method in a class i've got, but when i try the same process for say, a second function with an argument, i get a Page not found error. Is my routing the issue here, or is there a problem with one of the methods?

Routing:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'front/index/$1';
$route['/category/(:any)'] = 'front/category/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'front';
```

Database Model (News_model.php)

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct() {
                $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_news_latest() {
            $query = $this->db->get('chanl_posts', 20);
            return $query->result_array();      
        }

        public function get_news_category($category) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('chanl_posts', array('category' => $category));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
}
```

Controller (Front.php)

```
class Front extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('news_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function category($category)
        {
                $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news_category($category);

                if (empty($data['news_item']))
                {
                        show_404();
                }

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('front/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function index() {
                $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news_latest();

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('front/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter for your Index ?

$route['(:any)'] = 'front/index/$1';

and by the way, you index function are not expecting any parameter

index()

Answer (score 0):

Try these routes

```
$route['category'] = 'front';
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'front/category/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'front';
```